# How to split long string by newline in asp.net mvc view template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

I want split Javascript code by newlines, but the compiler gives me an error:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Delete", "delete", new { id = Model.Id }, 
            new { 
                @class="button-link", 
                onclick = " javascript;
                  javascript goes here; 
                  javascript goes here; 
                  javascript goes here;
                return false;"
        }
    ); %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) -- starting the string with the `@` symbol -- but it probably makes more sense to move your JavaScript out into a separate `.js` file, [as Darin suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144797/how-to-split-long-string-by-newline-in-asp-net-mvc-view-template/4144847#4144847).

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Delete", "delete", new { id = Model.Id },
                    new {
                            @class = "button-link",
                            onclick = @"javascript;
                                        javascript goes here;
                                        javascript goes here;
                                        javascript goes here;
                                        return false;"
                        });
%>
```

Comment: How about this in javscript code $('" + Html.AntiForgeryToken() + "')

Answer (score 1):

Not directly answering your question but proposing an alternative: javascript has nothing to do in HTML and both should never be mixed. It should be in a separate file:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(
    "Delete", "delete", new { id = Model.Id }, 
    new { @class = "button-link", id = "foo" }); %>
```

and then in a **separate** js file (using jquery):

```
$(function() {
    $('#foo').click(function() {
        // TODO: put as many lines of javascript as you wish here
        return false;
    });
});
```

This way your markup is smaller, static resources such as javascript is cached by the client browser and you don't need to worry about simple, double, triple quotes, ...

Comment: I know that your solution is better, but how deal with placements like this $('" + Html.AntiForgeryToken() + "').val()

Comment: one way is declare global variable in head of page something like this var csrf_token = "token" and call this in separate js file, i think this is bad idea, any suggestions?

Comment: You could have a form containing the antiforgery token and then simply use the [jquery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) to AJAXify it. No need to use actionlinks.